# Why all the alert boxes are rendered first in Javascript.?

Tags: javascript

For example:

```js
document.write("rishabh");
functionHello("v");
function functionHello(str)
{

  alert(str);
  alert("Hello apple");
}
var x=5;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>rishabh</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now when I am running this html , first of all alert messages popups are displayed, then only other text is rendered on the browser screen.

In debugging mode, everything is occuring sequentially. Why that difference is coming?

Any inputs?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e6ud1L1a/1 looks fine to me. I removed that pesky alert(str1) since str1 doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: You are asking why the document.write appears to execute after the alert?

Comment: `str1` is not defined, so an errors occurs and the script stop here.

Comment: firstly text add to body of page and then alert run 
str1 is not defined
what you need to do ?

Comment: Hi All,
even if you remove str1 then also alert boxes are rendered first, then only all the text is written to the browser

Answer (score 0):

In debug mode I would guess a break point after the document.write also triggers a DOM render, but in production the DOM render is only triggered after the script finishes.

Comment: Hey Bruce,

if I remove the alert boxes, then the execution is sequential, only alert boxes are rendered first, other script contents are rendered sequentially

Comment: To clarify, by render the DOM, I mean actually draw the stuff you added to your document on the screen. In a browser environment, you don't control when this happens. If the browser has some dead time, it will likely perform this task. If you want to see the DOM update before your alert boxes, you can delay them slightly by wrapping in a setTimeout: setTimeout (function () {alert (str); ...},100);